# Swift 5.0 Circular UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton

As the title says, I want to create a circular UIButton. However, the course I'm currently following is (somewhat) outdated and I was not able to find a working solution to why this piece of code is not working. Most google searches ended up showing a somewhat same piece of code as I have here, but gave me the exact same error. Hopefully you guys can explain what I'm doing wrong here.

The piece of code including the error message:

[image: 1]

Comment: use init .. instead of awake from nib

Comment: remove keyword `class` from the function's signature, and optionally you may want to add these things to the `layoutSubviews()` merthod instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For future readers with a similar issue, please update the title, it is unrelated to the problem. See also [ask]. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear and has nothing to do with outdated code. It's probably a code completion mistake.

You cannot use **instance** variables in a **class** function, not even in Swift 1.

Remove `class` in the `awakeFromNib` line to apply the **instance** method

Answer (score 0):

remove keyword `class` from the function's signature and instead of frame use `bounds`

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
            layer.cornerRadius = max(bounds.maxY,bounds.maxX)/2
            layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
```

But better is to add `cornerRadius` in layout subviews

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
         layer.cornerRadius = max(bounds.maxY,bounds.maxX)/2
      }
```